# How can I get a gradient in gwt menu bar per showcase example?

Tags: gwt

In the Google Web Toolkit Showcase, the Menu Bar example (http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwMenuBar) displays the menu bar's background as a gradient.  However, when I use their css (clean.css from the gwt package), I get a solid background.

Does anyone know how to get the gradient?  There are no explicit references to 'gradient' in their css file.  FYI I'm testing this with iceweasel 3.5.15 (which is a essentially firefox 3.5.16).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not a gradient css style. Instead a background image is set ***hborder.png*** . You can see the style/background image as shown using Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox/Firebug

[image]

Comment: hborder.png is specified in the css file, e.g.: <br>.gwt-MenuBar-horizontal {
  background: #e3e8f3 url(images/hborder.png) repeat-x 0px -2003px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
} But this seems to be having no effect.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any 404 error i.e hborder.png not getting downloaded.

Comment: I've been concerned about that, but haven't seen any errors.  The png file is referenced in the css file by 'background #e38f3 url(images/hborder.png) ...'.  The images directory is in the same directory as the css file.  Both are in the 'client' java src package.

Comment: Could you test in latest chrome/firefox and confirm?

Answer (score 0):

(The above comment is a bit illegible and I can't edit it).

hborder.png is specified in the css file, e.g.

> .gwt-MenuBar-horizontal {
>    background: #e3e8f3 url(images/hborder.png) repeat-x 0px -2003px;
>    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
>   }

I would expect this to create the gradient, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.